# How to run an executable with time and memory usage limit?

Tags: c#

I want to run an executable and limit its memory and time usage. Of course
I want to know if it breached any of these things and if not I want the
data how much was used. What could I use from the .NET to do this?

Comment: This is not a programming question, even though you might want to do this because of a programming problem. I recommend it be moved to ServerFault.

Comment: I disagree, he wants to create a program to monitor an executable - not using out-of-the-box monitoring application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a **Thread** to monitor the executable you run.

```
var process = Process.Start("Test.exe");

//  Monitor - Use this property to monitor the memory
process.MainModule.ModuleMemorySize

//  Monitor - Use this property to monitor the time
process.StartTime

//  Limit - You can use this property to limit the executable memory size,
//  but I wouldn't recommend it...
process.MaxWorkingSet
```

*Good luck.*